# Mod rewrite - block access to dir except for certain files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

Currently I have the following, to restrict direct access to scripts except for three cases:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !read_dir [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !get_ac_options [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !view_log [NC]
RewriteRule ^inc/php /cms_spider3?script_access_attempt [NC]
```

The first two conditions work (that is, I can access both read_dir.php and get_ac_options.php) **but the third rule is ignored**.

That is to say, accessing

```
/my/server/view_log.php
```

...always results in the redirect. The only difference between view_log.php and the other two is that the other two are accessed always over AJAX, whereas view_log.php is accessed directly in the browser. I can't imagine this would cause a difference, but thought I'd mention it.

I'm no expert in mod-rewrite, so it's possible the entirety of what I have could be better written. (I'm not even sure what `[NC]` does - I just kept it from some example code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `it's possible the entirety of what I have could be better written.`

You rule can be better rewritten as:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(read_dir|get_ac_options|view_log) [NC]
RewriteRule ^inc/php /cms_spider3?script_access_attempt [L,NC]
```

NC is for `No Case` (ignore case matching)
L is for Last rule

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Damn, I could have sworn I tried exactly that but failed. Anyway, yours works - thanks a lot. (NB I did check the docs, but as ever they're fairly nuclear when you just need a quick resolution)

Comment: @Utkanos: Completely agree with you that mod_rewrite documentation is not intuitive and not use friendly.